# what is the sms drafts box uri in android?

Tags: android

i want read all sms in draft box of android i write an app that can read all sms in inbox sent box
but i dont know uri path of draft box in android
i should replace uri path of draft box with inbox to read all sms that are in drafts
but what is it?

```
   sms objSms = new sms();
        Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);

        int totalSMS = c.getCount();
        Log.i("READDDDDDDDD INBOX",totalSMS+"***************************" );
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

                objSms = new sms();

                objSms.setPhone(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                objSms.setMessage(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));

                objSms.setDate_time(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));



                ars.add(objSms);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        c.close();


        return ars;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMS draft URI is

```
content://sms/drafts/

Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/drafts/");
```

The whole list of SMS uris are:

```
Inbox = "content://sms/inbox"
Failed = "content://sms/failed"
Queued = "content://sms/queued"
Sent = "content://sms/sent"
Draft = "content://sms/draft"
Outbox = "content://sms/outbox"
Undelivered = "content://sms/undelivered"
All = "content://sms/all"
Conversations = "content://sms/conversations"
                "content://mms-sms/conversations"
```

Some are documented and rest are not/

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");
```

for more help check this

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/provider/Telephony.java